# Icon Property on Button causes Compiler Error

Tags: apache-flex, button

When I attempt to add an icon to a button like this:

```
<s:Button icon="@Embed(source='assets/logo.jpg')"/>
```

I receive this error:

```
Multiple markers at this line:
-Button
-Cannot resolve attribute 'icon' for component type spark.components.Button.
```

The documentation specifies that you can add an icon like that.  See [Button Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Button.html#styleSummary).

It is interesting because I can add other `Common Styles` with no trouble.  For example this compiles fine:

```
<s:Button color="#998877" fontSize="16"/>
```

What am I goofing up here?  Sure it is pretty simple.

Edit: There is also an example [right here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d9f.html).  The example uses version 4.6.  I am on version 4.

Comment: Your edit says it all: Spark Button doesn't have an 'icon' attribute in Flex 4.0. So either migrate to 4.5 or 4.6, use mx Button, or create a custom skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this when I first started using the spark components.  I was too was using the original Flex 4 version.  They originally didn't support an icon property.  You'd have to skin it to get it to work.  See the following link:

http://www.flexer.info/2009/06/12/how-to-skin-a-button-with-icon-in-flex-4-sdk-spark/

However, rather than using skins to just add a image to the button, I'd also suggest moving up to flex 4.5 and up.  Those include enhancements along with the addition of the icon property to the spark button.

Comment: I guess that this must be the correct answer.  But the documentation seems to suggest that the icon style is supported see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Button.html#styleSummary I have my products set to `Flex 4 and earlier` and Runtimes set to `Flex Player 11 and earlier`.  **Why do I still see the icon property if it does not exist in Flex 4?**

Comment: Not sure there.  The documentation definitely seems to suggest that the icon property is available in Flex 4, but i know that during compile time i got the same error.  Then i came across the above link on how to skin the button.  Shortly after that i discovered that 4.5 added icon property support, and immediately upgraded to Flash Builder 4.5

Comment: Makes sense.  Probably just a documentation typo.